# How is the average batting average calculated?

Tags: mlb

Sorry if this is an easy question but I cannot find the answer anywhere. I'm wondering how the average of all batting averages in the MLB is calculated. Do you add up all the batting averages and divide by the total number of players? Or do you count the total number of hits by all players and divide that by the total at bats for all players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the second method (total hits over total AB) would be valid.  If everyone has the same number of AB, they would be equivalent.

The first method would weight the average of someone with a single AB and someone with 500 AB as equal.  If you give them weight proportional to their AB count, then you just end up with the second method.

Comment: That's what I assumed but I couldn't find a source that said so. Thank you for confirming.